# can a wireless access point drop the entire network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Good day, i have a new 16 port switch with PCs and other devices connected but every now and then my network will drop,then i will have to reboot all units in my cabinet [Router, POE, Switch and D-link AP] recently when it dropped, i took off only the D-link AP and suddenly the network connection was re-established again.

I don't see any sense behind this, is there someone with better explanation as what could be the cause for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Couple of possibilities off the top of my head - the AP has compromised and there are ARP requests or something similar flooding and taking down your network, or maybe you have a routing loop ?

Comment: When this happens, do all pc's lose network connectivity?

Comment: Yes, all PCs connect to that switch loses connection

Answer (score 0):

It seems your devices is having an IP address conflict; i.e you have configured static IP addresses for your PC's, such as 192.168.1.2 for PC-01, etc. While PC-01 is off, your wireless devices asks for an IP on your router, since PC-01 is off, the router will give your wireless device 192.168.1.2, after which you power on PC-01 you won't get a IP because it is already taken.

Reconfiguring static IP for your workstations on a much higher address i.e 192.168.1.201 etc. will help by IP addresses not getting taken up by wireless devices.

Comment: I have used a static IP which outside the scope, so chances of IP conflict are 0. Thanks

Comment: An IP Conflict on an AP would not tear down the entire network, so this information is incorrect.